# SWIFT - MKMapRect rotation issue

Tags: swift, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d, mkmaprect

I am trying to reposition my MKMapView to show to the currently selected annotation at the bottom of the view.  The problem I run into is when the map has any rotation to it. It will only rotate back to default position, then stop and not move the mapView to the correct new position. If the mapView has no rotation, it works fine. Kinda hard to explain.

here is the code that is used to reposition the mapView

```
            //pinCoord are the coordinates from the selected annotation
            let mapRect = myMap.visibleMapRect
            let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(pinCoord)

            let nPx = point.x - mapRect.size.width*0.5
            let nPy = point.y - mapRect.size.height*0.95

            let newMapRect = MKMapRectMake(nPx, nPy, mapRect.size.width, mapRect.size.height)

            myMap.setVisibleMapRect(newMapRect, animated: true)
```

Here was a previous code I tried, that worked fine with any rotation. But had issues when the mapView had any tilt to it. So I decided to use the above code(though it would be simpler).

```
    let pinCGPoint = myMap.convertCoordinate(pinCoord, toPointToView: self.view)
    let currentCenterPoint = myMap.convertCoordinate(myMap.centerCoordinate, toPointToView: self.view)

    //create new y center point
    let point2y = view.frame.height - pinCGPoint.y
    let nYp = currentCenterPoint.y - point2y 

    //create new x center point
    let c2pX = currentCenterPoint.x - pinCGPoint.x
    let pointX = view.frame.width*0.5 - pinCGPoint.x

    let nXp = currentCenterPoint.x - pointX

    let newCenter = CGPointMake(nXp, nYp)
    let coord2 = myMap.convertPoint(newCenter, toCoordinateFromView: self.view)

    myMap.setCenterCoordinate(coord2, animated: true)
```

Any help would be great, thanks.